# Aligning span and small tags

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have some html like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <small class="text-muted text-small" style="display:inline-block" >Hello</small>
        <span style="display:inline-block"> World</span>

        <small class="text-muted text-small" style="display:inline-block" >Hello second time</small>
        <span style="display:inline-block"> World</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

It will look like:

```
Hello World
Hello second time World
```

But I want to arrange small tags into columns as well as span tags, so it will look like this:

```
Hello              World
Hello second time  World
```

I'm using bootstrap for styling, and tried assigning small tags col-md classes to manipulate, but it's not aligning as I'd want it to.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: apply a `min-width` to `.text-small`

Comment: You will need JS for this to calculate the space you need. There is no such way to do this dynamically by CSS only. But you could of course change the HTML structure to solve this (div's)

Comment: or use this style="display:inline-block; min-width:200px" min-width can be set to anything.

Comment: @Jelmer don't be too quick to jump to js...

Comment: @Pete you are right. I had a closer look on the HTML provided by OP and concluded I was reading it wrong because of the syntax highlighting in his desired result example. `Hello` and `World` are marked in another color so I thought those two had to be big and only the `second time` part had to be small. In that case it is hard, if not impossible, to fix it by CSS only because then the gap between the first `Hello` and `World` must be calculated to adopt to the width of the `second time` part in the second example. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this with the following styles:

```
li {display:inline-block;}
span {float:right; margin-left:1em;} 
/*the margin can be however large you want the gap between the words*/
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/9bpUg/1/)

sorry just tested in chrome and didn't work properly, for chrome you need to add

```
small {float:left; clear:both;}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/9bpUg/3/)